# How many combinatorially distinct ways are there to tile an equilateral triangle with $k$ $60^\circ-120^\circ$ trapezoids?

Tags: geometry, reference-request, combinatorial-geometry, tiling, oeis

I believe there is exactly one way (up to combinatorial equivalence) to arrange 3 trapezoids with angles of $60^\circ$ and $120^\circ$ into an equilateral triangle:

[image]

With $4$ trapezoids, I see two ways:

[image]

With $5$ trapezoids, there are many more; I count at least $13$ (thanks to Dan Uznanski for discovering the last of these):

[image]

In general, how many ways are there to do this with $k$ trapezoids, and what are the corresponding arrangements?

Knowing that the sequence starts $1,2,13?,\ldots$ isn't quite enough to try and find it on OEIS. (I'd also appreciate hearing about any configurations that I may have missed above.)

**Edit**: It seems that the terminology above was not clear to everyone, so two clarifications:

- When I say "trapezoids" here, I am referring only to those pictured above, where there is exactly one pair of parallel sides and the $60^\circ$ angles are adjacent; I am not including parallelograms with angles in cyclic order $(60^\circ, 120^\circ, 60^\circ, 120^\circ)$.
- Two arrangements are combinatorially equivalent if there is a bijection between the corners, edges, and faces of the two which preserves inclusion (e.g. of a vertex on a face or one line segment in another), adjacency, overlaps, and maps $60^\circ$ and $120^\circ$ angles in trapezoids to themselves. In other words, we care about the incidence structure of the trapezoids, and whether trapezoids $A$ and $B$ coincide along a shared leg, but not about specific lengths of line segments or a rotation of the large triangle.

Comment: What do you mean with "up to combinatorial equivalence"? If I'm not wrong, with 5 trapeziods, if you rotate the second you wrote you obtain exactly the trapezoid at his right side.

Comment: I think you have to be more careful describing the conditions. Do parallelograms count as trapezoids? Your last two examples show a parallelogram divided into two trapezoids. You can divide a parallelogram into as many trapezoids as you like if the ratio of its length to its height is small enough.

Comment: @Gabrielek: They are not equivalent. In each of the two you mention, there is a unique trapezoid $A$ which takes up an entire side of the triangle, and a unique trapezoid $B$ which does not touch the border of the triangle anywhere. In the first configuration, $A$ touches $B$ along a leg of $B$, while in the second $A$ touches $B$ along a base of $B$.

Comment: @EthanBolker: No, thanks for the observation; I will edit the original post to clarify that I mean trapezoids with angles of $60^\circ$ adjacent to each other. I agree that such constructions can be done with parallelograms, though I don't believe they lead to any more solutions with $k\le 5$.

Comment: You did not number the examples so in general - are mirror accepted as different?

Comment: @Moti: No, I am counting all combinatorially equivalent arrangements as identical. (This includes any rotations or flips of the large triangle.) I will edit the OP to clarify more precisely what I mean by "combinatorially equivalent".

Comment: Found one you missed.  https://imgur.com/WiyyvIw

Comment: @DanUznanski: Fantastic, thanks! I'll edit that one in.

Answer (score 1):

**Correction and revision added at the end**

An equilateral triangle tiled with $k$ $60^o-120^o$ trapezoids can be tiled with $k+1$ such trapezoids in at least six ways: by adding a tile along the whole of one side of the equilateral triangle, or by dividing one of the tiles whose base does not occupy an entire side of the triangle.  But when $k=3$, the first three arrangements for $k+1$ are equivalent under $120^o$ rotation, as are the second three, and so we have only two distinct tilings for $k=4$, as OP notes, which we may denote as $4a$ and $4b$.

We can add a tile to $4a$ in six distinct ways, as in the first six of OP's array for $k=5$ (reading left to right and down). Of the six ways to add a tile to $4b$, four are equivalent to one of the preceding six, and so we have only two distinct new tilings, the seventh and eighth in OP's illustration.

But we can also add a tile to $4b$ by re-dividing the divided trapezoid of $4b$ in one of the three ways shown in OP's ninth, eleventh, and twelfth figures of the array.

Lastly, reducing the number of concurrent lines from the sides of the triangle from three (as in all preceding cases) to two, i.e. by removing one of them, we can re-tile the remaining concave pentagon with four tiles in exactly two distinct ways, as in OP's tenth and thirteenth.

Thus from $4a$ and $4b$ we derive $5a$, $5b_1$ and $5b_2$, with distinct arrangements$$5a+5b_1+5b_2=6+2+5=13$$

If these thirteen distinct tilings for $k=5$ are complete, then for $k=6, 7, 8$ I find, by systematic counting, $68, 283, 1081$ distinct tilings, respectively.

Looking at these totals part by part, i.e. as generated by $5a+5b_1+5b_2$ and their descendants, we have

$$[1+1+1+1+1+1]+[1+1]+[1+1+1+1+1]=13$$for $k=5$,$$[1+2+3+6+6+6]+[3+1]+[8+8+8+8+8]=68$$for $k=6$,$$[1+3+6+24+24+24]+[6+0]+[39+39+39+39+39]=283$$for $k=7$, and$$[1+4+10+82+82+82]+[10+0]+[152+152+152+152+152]=1031$$for $k=8$.

**I.** In the bracketed $6$-sums on the left, the pattern of the first three (vertical) columns is clear: $1$'s in the first column, consecutive integers in the second, and consecutive triangle numbers in the third, starting from $1$. The greatest addend in each (horizontal) row is equal to the sum of the six addends in the row preceding. As a function of $k$, the sum of the first three terms in each row is thus given by$$\frac{k^2-5k+6}{2}$$The sequence of identical greatest terms in each row, easily extendable to $$1, 6, 24, 82, 261, 804, 2440, 7356, 22115,...$$ is given by the expression$$\Sigma\Sigma\frac{3^{k-4}-1}{2}$$where $k\ge5$. This is clear  since $$\Sigma\frac{3^{k-4}-1}{2}=1, 4, 13, 40, 121, 364,...$$and $$\Sigma\Sigma\frac{3^{k-4}-1}{2}=1(k-4)+4(k-5)+13(k-6)+40(k-7)+121(k-8)+...$$Thus by addition, the sum of the first bracketed row of six terms is$$\frac{k^2-5k+6}{2}+3[1(k-4)+4(k-5)+13(k-6)+40(k-7)+121(k-8)+...]$$**II.** For $k>6$, the second term derived from $4b_1$ yields no new tilings, and the bracketed middle addend is simply the triangle number given by$$\frac{k^2-7k+12}{2}$$**III.** Lastly, the sequence of each column of the $5$-sums on the right,$$1,8,39,152,526,1704,5322,16296,...$$is OEIS A097787:$$\frac{3^{n+5}}{32}-\frac{2n^4+32n^3+196n^2+556n+633}{96}$$And since $n=k-5$, this can be written as$$\frac{3^k}{32}-\frac{2k^4-8k^3+16k^2-4k+3}{96}$$

And so we seem to have a method for a $3$-step calculation of the number of distinct tilings of an equilateral triangle by $k$ $60^o-120^o$ trapezoids. It would be good to fuse the above expressions into a single expression in $k$, but I have not yet been able to do it.  The sequence of total distinct tilings $$1,2,13,68,283,1031,3449,10981,33994,103629,313354,943623,2835853,8514355,...$$does not appear in OEIS.

**Correction/Revision**

**I.** As OP’s comment points out, the above answer rests on a false premise, that every distinct $k+1$ tiling of the equilateral triangle arises either from the addition of one trapezoid along an entire side of a k-tiled triangle, or from the division of one of the trapezoidal tiles within the triangle by a line parallel to the trapezoid's base, as in the generation below of six $k=6$ tilings from the first of OP's thirteen $k=5$ tilings by adding a trapezoid along bottom, right, and left in the first row, and by bisecting in turn the three inner trapezoids in the second row. I followed this same order in producing and numbering all the arrangements initially found.
[image: six k=6 from one k=5]

But although this method finds (when duplicates are set aside) a portion of the distinct $k+1$ tilings of the triangle, it does not find all of them.  As the comment notes, the following tiling for $k=6$, for example, does not arise in this way from any of the distinct tilings for $k=5$.
[image: OP counterexample]
Indeed, even from OP's last five tilings for $k=5$, it appears there are **at least two** other ways to generate a $(k+1)$-tiling: transformation and trisection.

**II.** OP's #$2$ for $k=5$ arises by addition of one tile to $4a$, as in my method, but #$10$ does not arise from $k=4$ but rather by a **transformation** of #$2$ for $k=5$,
[image: #2-#10]
in which trapezoid $a$ expands into $b$ and $b$ in turn expands into $c$. Similarly, OP's #$13$ rotated is a modification of #$11$,
[image: transformation #11-#13]
by expansion of $a$ into $b$ and $b$ into $c$.

The figure above missing from my count for $k=6$ arises by a like transformation of arrangement #$9$ of the sixty-eight I initially found.[image: #9 to OP counterexample]
where again trapezoid $a$ has displaced some of $b$, and $b$ some of $c$, in the figure on the right compared with #$9$ on the left.

But such transformations commonly involve only two trapezoids, not three, and a single arrangement can yield more than one. Of distinct arrangements found by my method for $k=6$, seven of them yield one or two arrangements I missed. Figures on the left below are numbered by their place in the sixty-eight distinct arrangements I found for $k=6$ by addition/division from the (slightly re-ordered) thirteen figures for $k=5$, followed on the right by the primed figures my method missed.
[image: transformations #9, #14, #29]
[image: transformations #34, #37]
[image: transformation #45, #61]
Each of these transformations is a one-step process in which one trapezoid invades and incorporates part of an adjacent one, e.g. as in #$45$-#$45'$, or #$45$-#$45''$

Just as the last five of the (presumably) thirteen arrangements for $k=5$ were not discoverable by my method from the two arrangements for $k=4$, so for $k=6$ the ten (primed) arrangements above were missed by my method.

**III.** And the count is still not complete. OP's $9th$, $11th$, and $12th$ arrangements for $k=5$ arise by **trisection** of one of the trapezoids for $k=3$. Accordingly, if we trisect in turn each trapezoid of $4a$ and $4b$ in each of the three ways seen in OP's $9th$, $11th$, and $12th$ for $k=5$, the following six (of twenty-four possible) arrangements are new, and we now have $68+10+6=84$ distinct tilings for $k=6$.
[image: six by trisection]

**IV.** Similarly, exploring the possible arrangements for $k=7$, besides the $283$ found by addition/division applied to the arrangements for $k=6$, new arrangements appear both by the method of transformation as well as by the addition (by trisection) of two trapezoids to each distinct arrangement for $k=5$.  Since each trapezoid in an arrangement for $k=5$ can be trisected in three different ways, this raises the possibility of$$5\cdot13\cdot3=195$$new arrangements, although this is reduced to $125$ when $70$ duplicates are set aside.  Adding as well the nineteen new arrangements found to result from transformations gives$$283+19+125=427$$distinct arrangements for $k=7$.

It seems, then, there are three ways to generate a $k+1$ tiling: by adding one tile to a $k$-tiling, by adding (through trisection) two tiles to a $(k-1)$-tiling, and by transforming a $(k+1)$-tiling generated in one of the first two ways.  Are there other ways? If not, are the above revised counts accurate? In searching for combinatorially distinct arrangements, I find the systematic survey of possible transformations more difficult than that of possible trisections. OEIS does not recognize sequence$$1, 2, 13, 84, 427$$ so it seems an expression in $k$ for the number of distinct tilings of the triangle must await an accurate count at least through $k=8$, if a general rule is to appear.

Comment: I cannot follow this answer.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean when you say a dissection is "generated by" $5a$, $5b_1$, or $5b_2$. The dissections given by adding trapezoids to one of these constructions overlap with one another, so it's not clear to me why you can add them without doing some kind of inclusion/exclusion argument. I also don't understand why you can assume that all such tilings are generated in this manner, or what it means to reduce the number of concurrent lines. Can you provide more details or more precise descriptions in your answer?

Comment: I mean to say that every $6$-tiling must be a $5$-tiling with one tile added.  There are six ways to add a tile to the first eight of your 5-tilings and eight ways to add one to the last five.  This makes $88$ possible, but I find only $68$ are distinct.  Thus I see $5a$, $5b_1$, and $5b_2$ as the "ancestors" generating all possible tilings for larger $k$. Also, I noticed that in eleven of your tilings three lines concur, but not in your tenth and thirteenth, and in an effort to prove that your list for $k=5$ is complete, I suggest there are only two ways this can occur. I'll try to elaborate.

Comment: [Here](https://i.imgur.com/MQhXNsn.png) is a $6$-tiling that does not seem to me to be "a $5$-tiling with one tile added" by most definitions. Can you explain why you think all $6$-tilings should arise in such a manner?

Comment: A beautiful tiling, and not among the $68$ found by my method. I should have taken warning from your final five tilings for $k=5$, which do not arise from $4a$ and $4b$ as the first eight do, but rather from the sole tiling for $k=3$—by trisecting one of its trapezoids, as in your $9th$, $11th$, & $12th$, or by sacrificing two of its trapezoids to gain four, as in your $10th$ and $13th$ figures. I already see one I missed for $k=7$: divide one trapezoid from $k=3$ into five.  This does not arise by adding one tile to any of the distinct arrangements I found for $k=6$. I need to work on this.